# Get SQLite data over SFTP connection

Tags: python, sqlite, ssh, sftp, paramiko

I want a connection between a Windows and Linux PC. I am using Paramiko (SFTP):

```py
ssh_client = paramiko.SSHClient()
ssh_client.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy)
ssh_client.load_system_host_keys()
ssh_client.connect(ip, 22, user, pwd)
sftp_client = ssh_client.open_sftp()
```

I don't get an error so I think the connection works. But I am not able to get files from remote PC. I want to get SQLite database or its data:

```py
file = sftp_client.get("Data.db")
```

I don't know if SQLite databases aren't readable or editable or if I am just using the wrong syntax.

Comment: If you want to use a database that lives on a different computer, sqlite is not a good choice.

Answer (score 0):

Paramiko [`SFTPClient.get` method](https://docs.paramiko.org/en/latest/api/sftp.html#paramiko.sftp_client.SFTPClient.get) takes (at least) two arguments and does not return anything.

```
def get(self, remotepath, localpath, callback=None):
```

So it should be like:

```
sftp_client.get("/remote/path/Data.db", "/local/path/Data.db");
```

Or if you are on Windows:

```
sftp_client.get("/remote/path/Data.db", "C:\\local\\path\\Data.db");
```

---

If you actually do not want to download the file, but use it as if it were a local file, use [`SFTPClient.getfo`](https://pysftp.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pysftp.html#pysftp.Connection.getfo):

```
file = sftp_client.getfo("/remote/path/Data.db")
```

That returns a file-like object, which you can use in many Python APIs. Though I do not see any mention of [SQLite Python API](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sqlite3.html#sqlite3.connect) supporting file-like objects.

Even if it does, it can be quite slow to use. If you are going to modify a relatively large portion of the database, it might be faster to download whole database, do the changes locally and re-upload back.